# How to encode foreign characters in url in PHP

Tags: php, encoding

How do you correctly encode an URL with foreign characters in PHP?
I assumed urlencode() would do the trick but it does not.

The correct encoding for the following URL

```
http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/anachronos/Paddestøel/advanced
```

Is this:

```
http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/anachronos/Paddest%C3%B8el/advanced
```

But urlencode encodes it like this:

```
http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/anachronos/Paddest%F8el/advanced
```

What function do I use to encode it like on the second example?

Comment: It's all about your encoding. seems urlencode() encodes it as the Latin-1 value?

Comment: Make sure you're using utf8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP scripts seem to use some single-byte encoding. You can either:

- Save the source code as UTF-8
- Convert data to UTF-8 with [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)

In general, making the full switch to UTF-8 fixes all encoding issues at once but initial migration might require some extra work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct" encoding. URL-percent-encoding simply represents raw bytes. It's up to you what those bytes are or how you're going to interpret them later. If your string is UTF-8 encoded, the percent-encoded raw byte representation is `%C3%B8`. If your string is not UTF-8 encoded, it's something else. If you want `%C3%B8`, make sure your string is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Use UTF-8 encoding

```
function url_encode($string){
    return urlencode(utf8_encode($string));
}
```

Then use this function to encode your url (got it in a comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)